# Unable to do system restore, no XP CD

Tags: windows-xp, system-restore

I have a Balance PC with XP which I bought second-hand.  I had a freeze-up recently and then Windows started running unpredictably on me – reboots when shutting down, utilities not working correctly, problems with IE8 and Firefox, etc.

In the past I used system restore to correct the problem, but **I cannot get system restore to work** anymore.  I have tried every method on the Microsoft website except using the Windows XP installation CD and reinstalling, since I never got one from the seller (I have just discovered it was not included with the materials the seller gave me).

I had similar problems some time back and was able to restore but now system restore seems to be running but disabled, no matter which option I use.  There is no calendar that shows up if I try to restore to a previous backup; if I try to back out the previous restore the next window does not go anywhere; and when I choose the option to create a new restore point, I am not allowed to enter any data in the box. I also tried running in Safe Mode but that did not work either.

System restore is 'enabled' on the pc and I have more than sufficient freespace and the drive is being monitored.  I checked all these.  Any suggestions?

The program comes up but will not work properly; the system says it is 'enabled' but I am not allowed to use the options it gives me.

Comment: *> but now system restore seems to be running but disabled … System restore is enabled on the pc* So which is it?

Answer (score 1):

You may use a software to read your windows license key (there are several of those, easy to find with google) and then borrow a windows XP CD and re-install the system.

Creating a new restore point wouldn't be helpful even if it works, because you would make a backup of all the errors you have now.

Another possibility would be a system change to a free linux system... Maybe I am going to far with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think basically, you should get a program to rad your licence key, and do a format and re-install of windows. It's by far the easiest thing to do.

Comment: For example, Produkey: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html